# How to create a package with excel sheet data in AEM?

Tags: java, web, adobe, aem

So, I have to make a package using the package manager of CRXDE. I need to add hundreds of paths to the filter by copying each of them one by one and it takes a lot of time by doing so. Is there any way I can upload a data file such as excel or CSV where the file contains all the paths and I can just build a package with it?

Answer (score 1):

If the paths are query-able via AEM, you may try using the [Query Packager tool from ACS AEM Commons](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/packagers/query-packager/index.html).

Alternatively, you can write code to read through the CSV file and create the package programmatically.

Similar tools have already been created by a few people which you can leverage (see below) or build your own

1. [Create Package in AEM from Excel File](https://aem.redquark.org/2019/05/create-package-in-aem-from-excel-file.html)
2. [Selective content packaging](https://www.argildx.com/innovation/adxtools-selective-content-packaging/)